# Error: No named parameter with the name 'onSelectNotification' in flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am building a [wallpaper app](https://audiokumbh.com/sangh-shakha/rss-shakha/) in Flutter and got stuck in an error occured due to *flutter_local_notifications*
[image: No named parameter with the name 'onSelectNotification']

Using version of *flutter_local_notifications* : 10:0.0

I tried testing with few other versions

Code:

```
// details page

import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sliding_up_panel/sliding_up_panel.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper/wallpaper.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/blocs/ads_bloc.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/blocs/sign_in_bloc.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/models/content_model.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_app/utils/dialog.dart';
import '../blocs/data_bloc.dart';
import '../blocs/internet_bloc.dart';
import '../blocs/userdata_bloc.dart';
import '../models/config.dart';
import '../models/icon_data.dart';
import '../utils/circular_button.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String heroTag;
  final ContentModel d;

  DetailsPage({Key? key,required this.heroTag,required this.d}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _DetailsPageState createState() => _DetailsPageState();
}

class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {



  final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String progress = 'Set as Wallpaper or Download';
  bool downloading = false;
  late Stream<String> progressString;
  Icon dropIcon = Icon(Icons.arrow_upward);
  Icon upIcon = Icon(Icons.arrow_upward);
  Icon downIcon = Icon(Icons.arrow_downward);
  PanelController pc = PanelController();
  PermissionStatus? status;

  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  final Dio _dio = Dio();
  String? _fileName;

  Future<PermissionStatus> _requestPermissions() async {
    var permission = await Permission.storage.status;

    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      await Permission.storage.request().then((value){
        permission = value;
      });
    }

    return permission;
  }


  Future<Directory?> _getDownloadPath() async {
    Directory? directory;
    try {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      } else {
        directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
        // Put file in global download folder, if for an unknown reason it didn't exist, we fallback
        // ignore: avoid_slow_async_io
        if (!await directory.exists()) directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setState(() {
        progress = 'Problem with getting the directory. Try to restart the app';
      });
    }
    return directory;
  }


  Future<void> _download() async {
    await _getDownloadPath().then((Directory? dir)async{
    if(dir != null){
      final isPermissionStatus = await _requestPermissions();
      final ib = context.read<InternetBloc>();
      await ib.checkInternet();
      if(ib.hasInternet){
      if (isPermissionStatus.isGranted) {
      final savePath = path.join(dir.path, _fileName);
        await _startDownload(savePath);
      } else{
        askOpenSettingsDialog();
      }
      }else{
        setState(() {
          progress = 'Please check your network connection!';
        });
      }

    }else{
      setState(() {
        progress = 'Problem with getting the directory. Try to restart the app';
      });
    }});
    
  }


  void _onReceiveProgress(int received, int total) {
    if (total != -1) {
      setState(() {
        progress = "Downloading: ${(received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}" + "%";
      });
    }
  }



  Future<void> _startDownload(String savePath) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> result = {
      'isSuccess': false,
      'filePath': null,
      'error': null,
    };

    try {
      final response = await _dio.download(
        widget.d.imagelUrl!,
        savePath,
        onReceiveProgress: _onReceiveProgress
      );
      result['isSuccess'] = response.statusCode == 200;
      result['filePath'] = savePath;
    } catch (ex) {
      result['error'] = ex.toString();
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        progress = 'Downloaded Successfully';
      });
      openCompleteDialog();
      await _showNotification(result);
    }
  }





  Future<void> _onSelectNotification(String json) async {
    final obj = jsonDecode(json);

    if (obj['isSuccess']) {
      OpenFile.open(obj['filePath']);
    } else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Error'),
          content: Text('${obj['error']}'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> downloadStatus) async {
    final String path = downloadStatus['filePath'];
    final BigPictureStyleInformation bigPictureStyleInformation = BigPictureStyleInformation(FilePathAndroidBitmap(path),);
    final String channelId = 'download';
    final String channelName = 'download';
    final int notificationId = widget.d.timestamp.hashCode;
    final android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channelId,
      channelName,
      priority: Priority.high,
      importance: Importance.max,
      subText: _fileName,
      styleInformation: bigPictureStyleInformation,


    );
    //final iOS = IOSNotificationDetails();
    final platform = NotificationDetails(android: android);
    final json = jsonEncode(downloadStatus);
    final isSuccess = downloadStatus['isSuccess'];

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      notificationId, // notification id
      isSuccess ? 'Download Success' : 'Failure',
      isSuccess ? 'Image has been downloaded successfully! Click here to open it' : 'There was an error while downloading the file.',
      platform,
      payload: json
    );
  }



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fileName = '${widget.d.category}${widget.d.timestamp}.png';
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    final android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    final initSettings = InitializationSettings(android: android);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSettings, onSelectNotification: (payload) => _onSelectNotification(payload!),);
  }



  void openSetDialog() async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: Text('SET AS'),
          contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 40, bottom: 20, right: 40),
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              leading: circularButton(Icons.format_paint, Colors.blueAccent),
              title: Text('Set As Lock Screen'),
              onTap: () async {
                await _setLockScreen();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              leading: circularButton(Icons.donut_small, Colors.pinkAccent),
              title: Text('Set As Home Screen'),
              onTap: () async {
                await _setHomeScreen();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              leading: circularButton(Icons.compare, Colors.orangeAccent),
              title: Text('Set As Both'),
              onTap: () async {
                await _setBoth();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            Center(
              child: TextButton(
                child: Text('Cancel'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  //lock screen procedure
  _setLockScreen() {
    Platform.isIOS
        ? setState(() {
            progress = 'iOS is not supported';
          })
        : progressString = Wallpaper.imageDownloadProgress(widget.d.imagelUrl!);
    progressString.listen((data) {
      setState(() {
        downloading = true;
        progress = 'Setting Your Lock Screen\nProgress: $data';
      });
      print("DataReceived: " + data);
    }, onDone: () async {
      progress = await Wallpaper.lockScreen();
      setState(() {
        downloading = false;
        progress = progress;
      });

      openCompleteDialog();
    }, onError: (error) {
      setState(() {
        downloading = false;
      });
      print("Some Error");
    });
  }

  // home screen procedure
  _setHomeScreen() {
    Platform.isIOS
        ? setState(() {
            progress = 'iOS is not supported';
          })
        : progressString = Wallpaper.imageDownloadProgress(widget.d.imagelUrl!);
    progressString.listen((data) {
      setState(() {
        //res = data;
        downloading = true;
        progress = 'Setting Your Home Screen\nProgress: $data';
      });
      print("DataReceived: " + data);
    }, onDone: () async {
      progress = await Wallpaper.homeScreen();
      setState(() {
        downloading = false;
        progress = progress;
      });

      openCompleteDialog();
    }, onError: (error) {
      setState(() {
        downloading = false;
      });
      print("Some Error");
    });
  }

  // both lock screen & home screen procedure
  _setBoth() {
    Platform.isIOS
        ? setState(() {
            progress = 'iOS is not supported';
          })
        : progressString = Wallpaper.imageDownloadProgress(widget.d.imagelUrl!);
    progressString.listen((data) {
      setState(() {
        downloading = true;
        progress = 'Setting your Both Home & Lock Screen\nProgress: $data';
      });
      print("DataReceived: " + data);
    }, onDone: () async {
      progress = await Wallpaper.bothScreen();
      setState(() {
        downloading = false;
        progress = progress;
      });

      openCompleteDialog();
    }, onError: (error) {
      setState(() {
        downloading = false;
      });
      print("Some Error");
    });
  }




  void openCompleteDialog() async {
    AwesomeDialog(
        context: context,
        dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES,
        title: 'Complete',
        animType: AnimType.SCALE,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 80,
              child: Text(
                progress,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              )),
        ),
        btnOkText: 'Ok',
        dismissOnTouchOutside: false,
        btnOkOnPress: () {
          context.read<AdsBloc>().showInterstitialAdAdmob();        //-------admob--------
          //context.read<AdsBloc>().showFbAdd();                        //-------fb--------
          
        }).show();
  }

  askOpenSettingsDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Grant Storage Permission to Download'),
            content: Text(
                'You have to allow storage permission to download any wallpaper fro this app'),
            contentTextStyle:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Open Settins'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  await openAppSettings();
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Close'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final DataBloc db = Provider.of<DataBloc>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: SlidingUpPanel(
          controller: pc,
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
          minHeight: 120,
          maxHeight: 450,
          backdropEnabled: false,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
          body: panelBodyUI(h, w),
          panel: panelUI(db),
          onPanelClosed: () {
            setState(() {
              dropIcon = upIcon;
            });
          },
          onPanelOpened: () {
            setState(() {
              dropIcon = downIcon;
            });
          },
        ));
  }





  // floating ui
  Widget panelUI(db) {

    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
                child: dropIcon,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              pc.isPanelClosed ? pc.open() : pc.close();
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      Config().hashTag,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${widget.d.category} Wallpaper',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                      size: 22,
                    ),
                    StreamBuilder(
                      stream: firestore.collection('contents').doc(widget.d.timestamp).snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
                        if (!snap.hasData) return _buildLoves(0);
                        return _buildLoves(snap.data['loves']);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400]!,
                                  blurRadius: 10,
                                  offset: Offset(2, 2))
                            ]),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.format_paint,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () async {
                        final ib =  context.read<InternetBloc>();
                        await context.read<InternetBloc>().checkInternet();
                        if (ib.hasInternet == false) {
                          setState(() {
                            progress = 'Check your internet connection!';
                          });
                        } else{
                          openSetDialog();
                        }
                        
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Set Wallpaper',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 13,
                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey[400]!,
                                  blurRadius: 10,
                                  offset: Offset(2, 2))
                            ]),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.donut_small,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        _download();
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Download',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 13,
                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 5,
                    height: 30,
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      progress,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLoves(loves) {
    return Text(
      loves.toString(),
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 16),
    );
  }

  // background ui
  Widget panelBodyUI(h, w) {
    final SignInBloc sb = Provider.of<SignInBloc>(context, listen: false);
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: h,
          width: w,
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          child: Hero(
            tag: widget.heroTag,
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: widget.d.imagelUrl!,
              imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              ),
              placeholder: (context, url) => Icon(Icons.image),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                  Center(child: Icon(Icons.error)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 60,
          right: 20,
          child: InkWell(
            child: Container(
                height: 40,
                width: 40,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                child: _buildLoveIcon(sb.uid)),
            onTap: () {
              _loveIconPressed();
            },
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 60,
          left: 20,
          child: InkWell(
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.close,
                size: 25,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLoveIcon(uid) {
    final sb = context.watch<SignInBloc>();
    if (sb.guestUser == false) {
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
          if (!snap.hasData) return LoveIcon().greyIcon;
          List d = snap.data['loved items'];

          if (d.contains(widget.d.timestamp)) {
            return LoveIcon().pinkIcon;
          } else {
            return LoveIcon().greyIcon;
          }
        },
      );
    } else {
      return LoveIcon().greyIcon;
    }
  }




  _loveIconPressed() async {
    final sb = context.read<SignInBloc>();
    if (sb.guestUser == false) {
      context.read<UserBloc>().handleLoveIconClick(context, widget.d.timestamp, sb.uid);
    } else {
      await showGuestUserInfo(context);
    }
  }
}
```

tried changing **onSelectNotification** to **onDidReceiveNotificationResponse**
tried upgrading, cleaning downgrading notification pkg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `flutter_local_notifications` version 10.0.0 then you need to use the parameter `onDidReceiveNotificationResponse`. You can see the declaration here:

```
  Future<bool?> initialize(
    InitializationSettings initializationSettings, {
    DidReceiveNotificationResponseCallback? onDidReceiveNotificationResponse,
    DidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponseCallback?
        onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse,
  }) async {
```

https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/flutter_local_notifications-v10.0.0/flutter_local_notifications/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart#L121

If you are having problems with the version, then close the editor and execute the following commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
```